# Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined in VueJS

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I am new to VueJS and I am trying to import the terminal in React from https://github.com/nitin42/terminal-in-react into my VueJS project using the Vuera package (https://github.com/akxcv/vuera).

My App.vue file looks roughly like this:

```
<template>
    <div id ="app">
      <my-react-terminal/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import MyReactTerminal from './components/Terminal.vue'

export default {
    name: 'App',

    components: {
        MyReactTerminal
    },
}
```

My Terminal.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Terminal from 'terminal-in-react';

class MyReactTerminal extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Terminal/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyReactTerminal;
```

My Terminal.vue file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-react-terminal/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { MyReactTerminal }   from './Terminal.js';

  export default {
    components: { "my-react-terminal": MyReactTerminal}
  }
</script>
```

My main.js file is the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { VuePlugin } from 'vuera'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VuePlugin)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

And my .babelrc file is:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]    ,
  "plugins": ["vuera/babel"]
}
```

The errors I am getting are the following:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined"

found in

---> <ReactWrapper>
       <MyReactTerminal>
         <MyReactTerminal> at src/components/Terminal.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1862
callHook @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4219
insert @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3139
invokeInsertHook @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6346
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6565
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
eval @ main.js?56d7:9
./src/main.js @ app.js:4656
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:790
fn @ app.js:101
1 @ app.js:4682
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:790
(anonymous) @ app.js:857
(anonymous) @ app.js:860


vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
    at makeReactContainer (vuera.cjs.js?b8ae:339)
    at VueComponent.mountReactComponent (vuera.cjs.js?b8ae:352)
    at VueComponent.mounted (vuera.cjs.js?b8ae:362)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4219)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3139)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6346)
    at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6565)
    at Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945)
    at Vue.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
```

Please let me know if you need more information to replicate this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that component function was expected at some point, but `undefined` was provided. Since components have their own modules, the problem can be narrowed down.

This presumes that a component is named export:

```
import { MyReactTerminal } from './Terminal.js';
```

While components are commonly default exports when they have their own modules, this is true for this case as well.

It should be:

```
import MyReactTerminal from './Terminal.js';
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried your solution and I got vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.